OpenMP slowing down the run time
i need help parallelizing this chunk of code, i know having !$omp parallel inside the loop will slow it down so i have to place it outside, but doing so is creating false values
    !$omp parallel  
        do i=1, Nt

            !$omp do private(i1)
            do i1=2, n-1
               df1(i1)=(f0(i1)-f0(i1-1))/dx
               df2(i1)=(f0(i1+1)-2*f0(i1)+f0(i1-1))/(dx**2)
               F(i1)=-V*df1(i1)+D*df2(i1)
            end do
            !$omp end do

        ! periodic boundary conditions
            df1(1)=df1(n-1)
            df1(n)=df1(2)
            df2(1)=df2(n-1)
            df2(n)=df2(2)
            F(1)=-V*df1(1)+D*df2(1)
            F(n)=-V*df1(n)+D*df2(n)
        ! time stepping loop, not parallelized
            do j=1, n
                f0(j)=f0(j)+dt*F(j)
            end do

        end do
    !$omp end parallel

UPDATE : with this code the results are correct, but the none parallelized version is faster than the ones with openmp

    !$omp parallel private(i, i1, j) 
        do i=1, Nt

            !$omp do schedule(runtime)
            do i1=2, n-1
                         df1(i1)=(f0(i1)-f0(i1-1))/dx
             df2(i1)=(f0(i1+1)-2*f0(i1)+f0(i1-1))/(dx**2)
             F(i1)=-V*df1(i1)+D*df2(i1)
                    end do
            !$omp end do

!$omp single
        ! periodic boundary conditions
            df1(1)=df1(n-1)
            df1(n)=df1(2)
            df2(1)=df2(n-1)
            df2(n)=df2(2)
            F(1)=-V*df1(1)+D*df2(1)
            F(n)=-V*df1(n)+D*df2(n)
        ! time stepping loop, not parallelized
!$omp end single            
            !$omp do 
            do j=1, n
                f0(j)=f0(j)+dt*F(j)
            end do
            !$omp end do

        end do
    !$omp end parallel

I have already tried keeping the parallelizing inside the loop, adding shared and private, i either get wrong results for f0 or the run time keeps increasing

It will be much easier to answer this if you a provide a minimal, reproducible example and exactly how you compiled it - we want to try to reproduce what you have done and see what you can see, with what you have provided we can't do that.

Also please expand on "false values". Please tell us exactly what is going wrong.

That said the last do j=1, n is being performed by all threads, and hence all threads are adding into f0(j), is this what you want? Without telling us what the correct answers should be and showing us the wrong answers we can't say - but given this is also produces a race condition it's almost certainly wrong.

by false values i mean the parallelization is not done right, i get a different result for everytime i change the number of threads. i have actually fixed the parallelization and will post the most recent code, however, the speed problem is not solved, the code run with open mp is slower. i dont think i can upload the whole code because its for a graded assignement.

Yes, but for future tells us tell us exactly what is wrong, not just that something is wrong. Exactly which elements of which array has incorrect values? Why do you believe they are incorrect? We are coming to this totally out of the blue, while you may have been thinking about it for many  hours - try to make our introduction to it as easy as possible.

How big is n? How exactly are you compiling the code, both with and without OpenMP?

@IanBush The initial code has a data race on the variable i. In case of a data race, the behavior of the program is undefined. I'm surprised that it actually terminated and did not deadlock. Looking at individual values for a program with UB is tedious.

sorry about that, i am evaluating f0, n is now 50, and nt is 1250000, i have set a stability condition and iit is stable, the goal of the assignement is to write a code thats fast so the values can be whatever. my current problem is on the most recent update, code is running for almost 2 seconds for 1 thread, keeps increasing with the threads number, i have tried it on 2 different machines so it cant be that the problem. thank you for your time.

n=50 is much to small to show any parallel speed up. Try increasing it and decreasing the number of timesteps.

it makes sense, now its speeding up from 1 thread til 4 threads, but anything above is extremely slow, what could it be due to?

"anything above" is totally unclear. Please be more specific. And "now its speeding up from 1 thread til 4 threads": what is behind the "now", what did you change?

anything above 4 threads

You don't say how large n is. Distributing the work to many threads makes sense only if there is enough work for each of them, otherwise the overheads of the distribution can get larger than the expected speed-up.

Also you don't say what is your hardware (CPU model).

Scalability of the code is limited by multiple factors. Each I iteration contains three barriers and significant serial computation.  Serial computation limits scalability according to Amdahl. Barriers are not directly represented in Amdahl's formula, but you can estimate barrier with O(log(p)) serial runtime and significant constant execution time. Try to refactor your algorithm to avoid serial calculation and remove the need for 3 barriers. If you have only a low number of cores, scalability will also be limited by available hardware. Hyper threads usually don't scale linearly.

OK, as you won't provide one I've knocked together a simple driver for the above, and picked some parameters for the method more or less at random, just avoiding those that cause a numerical explosion - as long as NaNs aren't being created the times should be reasonable. This is not my area at all so I have no idea what good values for V, D and dt should be.
I also note you use a schedule clause on the main loop set to runtime. This seems an unnecessary complication to me, this is an obvious case for simple static scheduling, as such I have set the environment variable OMP_SCHEDULE to the value static
Finally I have scoped all the variables in the parallel region along with using default( none ), I strongly suggest you follow this practice - if you were my student I would mark you down significantly for not doing this.
Anyway the code looks like
Program omp

  Use, Intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, Only : wp => real64, li => int64

  !$ Use omp_lib, Only : omp_get_max_threads 
  
  Implicit None( Type, External )

  Real( wp ), Parameter :: pi = 4.0_wp * Atan( 1.0_wp )
  
  Integer, Parameter :: Nt = 100000

  Real( wp ), Dimension( : ), Allocatable :: f0
  Real( wp ), Dimension( : ), Allocatable :: F
  Real( wp ), Dimension( : ), Allocatable :: df1, df2

  Real( wp ) :: dx
  Real( wp ) :: dt = 0.00000001_wp
  Real( wp ) :: V = 0.1_wp
  Real( wp ) :: D = 0.001_wp

  Integer( li ) :: start, finish, rate
  
  Integer :: n
  !$ Integer :: nth_tmp
  Integer :: i, i1, j

  Character( Len = 6 ) :: nth
  
!!$  Write( *, * ) 'n ?'
  Read ( *, * ) n

  dx = 1.0_wp / n

  Allocate( f0( 1:n ) )
  Allocate( F ( 1:n ) )

  Allocate( df1( 1:n ) )
  Allocate( df2( 1:n ) )
  
  f0 = [ ( Sin( 2.0_wp * pi * i * dx ),  i = 1, n ) ] 

  nth = "Serial"
  !$ nth_tmp = omp_get_max_threads()
  !$ Write( nth, '( i0 )' ) nth_tmp
  
  Call System_clock( start, rate )
  !$omp parallel default( none ) &
  !$omp          shared ( n, dx, dt, V, D, f0, F, df1, df2 ) &
  !$omp          private( i, i1, j )  
  Do i=1, Nt

     !$omp do schedule(runtime)
     Do i1=2, n-1
        df1(i1)=(f0(i1)-f0(i1-1))/dx
        df2(i1)=(f0(i1+1)-2.0_wp*f0(i1)+f0(i1-1))/(dx**2)
        F(i1)=-V*df1(i1)+D*df2(i1)
     End Do
     !$omp end do

     !$omp single
     ! periodic boundary conditions
     df1(1)=df1(n-1)
     df1(n)=df1(2)
     df2(1)=df2(n-1)
     df2(n)=df2(2)
     F(1)=-V*df1(1)+D*df2(1)
     F(n)=-V*df1(n)+D*df2(n)
     ! time stepping loop, not parallelized
     !$omp end single            
     !$omp do 
     Do j=1, n
        f0(j)=f0(j)+dt*F(j)
     End Do
     !$omp end do

  End Do
  !$omp end parallel
  Call system_clock( finish, rate )

  Write( *, * ) 'threads, time, Checksum: ', &
       nth, Real( finish - start, wp ) / rate, Sum( Abs( f0 ) )
  
End Program omp

and with gfortran I compile it as follows:
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ gfortran --version

GNU Fortran (GCC) 14.1.0
Copyright © 2024 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ gfortran  -Wall -Wextra -Ofast -g -std=f2018 speed.f90 -o serial
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ gfortran  -fopenmp -Wall -Wextra -Ofast -g -std=f2018 speed.f90 -o parallel

I used the following script to help me run the program on varying number of threads and problem sizes on my (not very quiet) 4 core laptop:
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ cat runit
#!/usr/bin/bash

n=$1

./serial <<EOF
$n
EOF

for nth in 1 2 3 4
do
    export OMP_NUM_THREADS=$nth
    ./parallel <<EOF
$n
EOF
done

And some results
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ ./runit 100
 threads, time, Checksum: Serial   3.7813894000000001E-002   63.638517731294677     
 threads, time, Checksum: 1        6.6722949000000004E-002   63.638517731294677     
 threads, time, Checksum: 2        9.4060747000000000E-002   63.638517731294677     
 threads, time, Checksum: 3       0.11382194399999999        63.638517731294677     
 threads, time, Checksum: 4       0.13759535100000000        63.638517731294677     
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ ./runit 1000
 threads, time, Checksum: Serial  0.13271654599999999        636.59242131285487     
 threads, time, Checksum: 1       0.16490009400000000        636.59242131285487     
 threads, time, Checksum: 2       0.15034453500000000        636.59242131285487     
 threads, time, Checksum: 3       0.15836609099999999        636.59242131285487     
 threads, time, Checksum: 4       0.15964677499999999        636.59242131285487     
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ ./runit 10000
 threads, time, Checksum: Serial   1.5402481520000000        6365.9449356557152     
 threads, time, Checksum: 1        1.4769430800000001        6365.9449356557152     
 threads, time, Checksum: 2       0.83346241799999998        6365.9449356557152     
 threads, time, Checksum: 3       0.64971254300000003        6365.9449356557152     
 threads, time, Checksum: 4       0.53164672300000004        6365.9449356557152     
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ ./runit 100000
 threads, time, Checksum: Serial   20.154403815999999        63659.462735156230     
 threads, time, Checksum: 1        24.292843486999999        63659.462735156252     
 threads, time, Checksum: 2        13.762875521000000        63659.462735156252     
 threads, time, Checksum: 3        9.9385426639999999        63659.462735156252     
 threads, time, Checksum: 4        8.0076960939999999        63659.462735156252     

It can be seen that code code slows down for n=100, slows a small speed up on two threads for n=1000 but slows again at 3 and 4 threads, shows speed up all the way to 4 threads when n=10000 and is even better when n=100000. The reason for this is, as noted in the comments, that as the system size increases the importance of the overhead introduced due to parallelism when compared to the work decreases as the length of the vectors increases - at a fixed number of threads the overhead is ~constant at 3 barriers per iteration of the time loop but the work time increases linearly with the system size, hence the overhead disappears as n increases.
I also ran the intel compiler version - it shows virtually the same behaviour:
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ export OMP_SCHEDULE=static
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ ifx -O3 speed.f90 -o iserial
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ ifx -qopenmp -O3 speed.f90 -o iparallel
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ cat irunit
#!/usr/bin/bash

n=$1

./iserial <<EOF
$n
EOF

for nth in 1 2 3 4
do
    export OMP_NUM_THREADS=$nth
    ./iparallel <<EOF
$n
EOF
done

    
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ ./irunit 100
 threads, time, Checksum: Serial  4.064300000000000E-002   63.6385177312947     
 threads, time, Checksum: 1       2.181600000000000E-002   63.6385177312947     
 threads, time, Checksum: 2       9.437800000000000E-002   63.6385177312947     
 threads, time, Checksum: 3       0.126435000000000        63.6385177312947     
 threads, time, Checksum: 4       0.153296000000000        63.6385177312947     
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ ./irunit 1000
 threads, time, Checksum: Serial  0.125659000000000        636.592421312855     
 threads, time, Checksum: 1       0.178205000000000        636.592421312855     
 threads, time, Checksum: 2       0.166180000000000        636.592421312855     
 threads, time, Checksum: 3       0.182477000000000        636.592421312855     
 threads, time, Checksum: 4       0.184732000000000        636.592421312855     
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ ./irunit 10000
 threads, time, Checksum: Serial   1.47372400000000        6365.94493565571     
 threads, time, Checksum: 1        1.70136900000000        6365.94493565571     
 threads, time, Checksum: 2       0.920539000000000        6365.94493565571     
 threads, time, Checksum: 3       0.713782000000000        6365.94493565571     
 threads, time, Checksum: 4       0.608429000000000        6365.94493565571     
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ ./irunit 100000
 threads, time, Checksum: Serial   35.9102110000000        63659.4627351538     
 threads, time, Checksum: 1        17.9405890000000        63659.4627351538     
 threads, time, Checksum: 2        9.67623400000000        63659.4627351538     
 threads, time, Checksum: 3        7.31490800000000        63659.4627351538     
 threads, time, Checksum: 4        5.74371900000000        63659.4627351538     
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ 

TLDR:
Parallel computing is for solving large problem sizes!
